# Download file from Slack in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slack-api

I'm trying to work with the Slack API in Ruby. They have this snippet as an example on their site

```
def fetch_and_compose_image(file, channel)

  filename = file.timestamp

  if file.filetype == "jpg"
    File.open("./tmp/#{filename}", 'wb') do |f|
      f << fetch_image(file.url_private)
    end

    fd = FaceDetection.new

    if fd.process_image
      file_id = upload(file, channel)
      add_reactions(file_id, fd)
    end
  end
end
```

What I don't understand is, how are they adding the fetched image to 'f', and then somehow uploading the file with the variable 'file'. Where does 'f' come into play?

Comment: Do you have the link of where you took this snippet from?

Comment: Yup, this page https://api.slack.com/tutorials/working-with-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about this block

```
File.open("./tmp/#{filename}", 'wb') do |f|
  f << fetch_image(file.url_private)
end
```

then it is writing the file in binary mode(that's what `wb` is doing there) , then it is writing the content to file and then closing the file , same can be achieved with

```
to_write_file = File.open("./tmp/#{filename}", 'wb')
to_write_file << fetch_image(file.url_private)
to_write_file.close
```

but the first method is good way of defining it.

Answer (score 1):

So, here is the fetch_image method

```
def fetch_image(url)
  res = RestClient.get(url, { "Authorization" => "Bearer #{@team.access_token}" })

  if res.code == 200
    return res.body
  else
    raise 'Download failed'
  end
end
```

Which is needed in your controller/model.

This is a rough example, I admit, but basically, the file download is the first part of this script. You want to use this part:

```
filename = file.timestamp

if file.filetype == "jpg"
  File.open("./tmp/#{filename}", 'wb') do |f|
    f << fetch_image(file.url_private)
  end
end
```

You can then do something with f which is the file you downloaded. You can also use

```
file_path = open(file.url_private).path
```

to download the file.

In the provided example, they seem to use a model called FaceDetection and upload the file `file` to preform other tasks.

I hope this makes sense and helps.